# Whats the difference between the two subspaces?

Tags: vector-spaces, proof-verification

Hi all I have two questions regarding subspaces :

(a) Let $X_0$ be a fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $W_1=\{U\epsilon\mathbb{R}^n : U^TX_0=0 \}$

Is $W_1$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

(b) Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $W_2=\{U\epsilon\mathbb{R}^n : U^Ts=0 $ for all $ s\epsilon S\}$

Is $W_2$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$?

To me both the questions seems to be **awfully similar**. My initial guess was that they both were subspaces. Am I correct in this assumption ? I am stating here the process which I have followed to validate my claim.

**for (a)**
$X_0$ is the fixed vector. 
$W_1$ is non-empty since $\theta_{n} \epsilon W_1$ as the inner product of any vector i.e., $X_0$ with the zero vector ($\theta_n$) gives $0$.

Also assume $U,V\epsilon W_1$ , then $U^TX_0=0$ and $V^TX_0=0$.

Then $(U+V)^TX_0=(U^T+V^T)X_0=(U^TX_0+V^TX_0)$

So  $(U+V) \epsilon W_1$ and $W_1$ is closed under the usual laws of addition.

Also assume $U\epsilon W_1$ and $\alpha \epsilon \mathbb{R}$ then $U^TX_0=0$

Then $(\alpha U)^TX_0=(\alpha U^T)X_0=\alpha (U^TX_0)=0$

So  $\alpha U \epsilon W_1$ and $W_1$ is closed under the usual laws of scalar multiplication.

Hence $W_1$ is a subspace.

To me **part (b)** looks actually the same and I would have followed the same logic to state that $W_2$ is also a subspace? **Please tell me where I am wrong ?**

P.S. Apologies for the bad formatting. I am new to the community. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Have you ever learned duality from projective geometry?

Comment: I have never even heard about projective geometry. Consider me a layman and please try to answer my query. I have very basic knowledge about vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part b) is essentially the same, except you have to explicitly quantify over all $s\in S$.

Another approach would be to observe that $W_2$ is the intersection of the set $W_1 (s)$, for all $s\in S$.  Since an intersection of subspaces is a subspaces, b) follows from a).

Comment: Would you perhaps add a little bit more and tell me explicitly what extra  details are required to be added to make $W_2$ essentially a subspace ? Please note that these questions are separately given. I just grouped them together as they seemed similar to me. Without referring to the first one can the second one be proved as a subspace ?

Comment: @roni The difference is that in one statement, you are proving "blah".  In the other statement, you have to prove "For every $s\in S$, blah".  The proof is the same, but the quantification over $S$ is essential.